# Adjacent Jsx elements must be wrapped in an e

Tags: reactjs

i have a very annoying error when trying to display stuff in react table , i would like to make a table and display all values in rows ,  but for some reason i  am getting this error saying Adjacent jsx elemetns must be wrapped in an enclosing element next to the line where im trying to map over results. Any help is greatly appreciated !! thanks!!!

```
import React from "react";

import "./index.css";


// could also import the sass if you have a loader at dayz/dayz.scss

import moment from 'moment';
import { tasksRef, timeRef } from './firebase';
const defaultColor = "#000";


class Show extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Events: [],
   loading: true
  };


      render(){

    const { Events, Loading } = this.state;
    const orderedcars = Events;

    let List;


    if (Loading) {
      List = <div className="TaskList-empty">Loading...</div>;
    } else {

      List = (      
   <div>

<table>
  <thead>

              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Event Name</th>

                <th scope="row">Event date</th>


                <th scope="row">Event timeRef</th>

                </tr>
                  </thead>
                   <tbody>

                 {Events.map(car => (

                  <tr>
                <td>{car.name}</td>
                   <td>{car.timeRef}</td>
                   <td>{car.description}</td>


              </tr>

              </tbody>
</table>
            ))}

            </div>
           );
      }
 return(


 <div>


 {List}



   </div>
        );
    }



}


export default Show;
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the closing tbody and table atgs should be outside map function as follows

```
   {Events.map(car => (

               <tr key={car.name}>
                   <td>{car.name}</td>
                   <td>{car.timeRef}</td>
                   <td>{car.description}</td>
               </tr>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to place the closing `</tbody>` and `</table>` tags outside of the function given to `Events.map`.

```js
List = (
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Event Name</th>
          <th scope="row">Event date</th>
          <th scope="row">Event timeRef</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Events.map(car => (
          <tr>
            <td>{car.name}</td>
            <td>{car.timeRef}</td>
            <td>{car.description}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```